# Flutter: StreamProvider returns null on list even when containing data

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to establish a stream between the Firestore server and my app. I am trying to retrieve a list of notes from the server to display in a `ListView` widget. However, I keep getting an error saying that the List that is being returned is null. Through debugging, I noticed that the snapshot does in fact contain the data I am trying to access, so something wrong is happening before the `_notesFromSnapshot` function is able to map each snapshot to a `Note` object, which leads me to believe that the app renders the `ListView` before the Stream has enough time to fetch all the data.

Edit: The list works if I change the StreamProvider to listen to `QuerySnapshot` instead of a list of notes, but I need the convenience of accessing custom objects.

NoteListScreen.dart

```
class NoteListScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: NavBar(title: 'My notes'),
      body: StreamProvider<List<Note>>.value(
        value: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).notes,
        child: NoteList(),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/note/create');
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

NoteList.dart

```
class NoteList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _NoteListState();
}

class _NoteListStateextends State<NoteList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final notes = Provider.of<List<Note>>(context);

    return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: notes.length,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^ Returns error: 'The getter 'length' was called on null.'

            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Card(
                child: NoteItem(
                  name: notes[index].name,
                ),
              );
            },
          );
  }
}
```

DatabaseService.dart

```
class DatabaseService {
  final String uid;

  DatabaseService({this.uid});

  // collection reference
  final CollectionReference _userCollection = Firestore.instance.collection('users');

  .....

  List<Note> _notesFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
      return Note(
        name: doc.data['name'],
      );
    });
  }

  Stream<List<Note>> get notes {
    return _userCollection
        .document(uid)
        .collection('notes')
        .snapshots()
        .map(_notesFromSnapshot);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding `.toList()` at the end of this function:

```
List<Note> _notesFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
      return Note(
        name: doc.data['name'],
      );
    }).toList();
  }
```